OpenAI library do not support vless protocol
I`m tried to use vless proxy for openai
import requests
from openai import OpenAI


proxies = {
    'vless': 'vless://proxy_data'
}


client = OpenAI(api_key="key", base_url=proxies.get("vless"))
responce = client.chat.completions.create(model="gpt-4", messages="Hi!")
print(responce.choices[0].message.content)


This code causes an error httpx.UnsupportedProtocol: Request URL has an unsupported protocol 'vless://'.
import requests

proxies = {
    'vless': 'vless://proxy_data'
}

r = requests.get("https://google.com", proxies=proxies)
print(r.status_code)

I try use requests for this however, I need to use the openai library.

Clarify what you are trying to achieve with the vless proxy and OpenAI library. Provide more context.
